# divs won't align despite float:left and display:inline-block

Tags: css, css-float, alignment

I'm trying to have the three `<div class="forward-link">` align to be all along the same baseline. I've tried `float:left` and `display:inline-block`, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
The site is made using php/Wordpress, but below is the rendered HTML and CSS.

Also, http://jsfiddle.net/mugUG/

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="landing-content">
    <div id="landing-brief">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/blog">Growing Edge Blog</a></h2>
                    <p>“Embrace the messy imperfect genius. Seek to be misunderstood by creative minds.” ~Ross Martin One thing I have learned over the years as an entrepreneur is that when I am in my most creative space, I have to release being a perfectionist and jump into my creative messiness. I need to create space that allows [...]</p>
                <div class="forward-link">
                    <p><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/home"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Continue Reading</span></a></p>
                </div><!-- end forward-link -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="index.php?page_id=27">Meet Mary Anne</a></h2>
                <p>Mary Anne is the founder of Growing Edge Coaching™, a coaching and consulting company, where she helps individuals and companies develop powerful strategies to move forward in their life, their work, or their business. Her coaching is founded on her 20 years of experience as a manager and senior leader in non-profits.</p>
                <div class="forward-link">
                    <p><a href="index.php?page_id=27"><span style="color:#b8bf33">More About Mary Anne</span></a></p>
                </div><!-- end forward-link -->
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="#">Recent Tweets</a></h2>
                <div id="twitter-feed">

                        <ul>
                                                    <li>
                        RT @LollyDaskal: regret is often the result of too many excuses. #leadfromwithin #leadership                            </li>
                                                    <li>
                        What you do in small doses becomes big doses in your life.                          </li>
                                                    <li>
                        RT @ThisIsSethsBlog: Seth's Blog: Two kinds of unique http://t.co/1TJ1Vuf9                          </li>
                                                    </ul>
                    </div><!-- end twitter-feed -->
                <div class="forward-link">
                    <p><a href="https://twitter.com/growing_edge"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Follow @Growing_Edge</span></a></p>
                </div><!-- end forward-link -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end brief -->
    <div id="landing-social">
        <h1>Growing Edge Coaching™ works with individuals and companies to attain positive actions and powerful results in their work and life.</h1>
        <div id="icons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/maryanneflanagan"><img src="http://growingedgecoaching.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/facebook.png" alt="Growing Edge Coaching Facebook" id="fb" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/growing_edge"><img src="http://growingedgecoaching.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/twitter.png" alt="Growing Edge Coaching Twitter" id="tw" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/maryanneflanagan"><img src="http://growingedgecoaching.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/linkedin.png" alt="Growing Edge Coaching Linked In" id="li" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end icons -->
    </div><!-- end social -->
    <div id="landing-contact-info">
        <p><span>PHONE</span> 917.238-9726 | <span>E-MAIL</span> <a href="mailto:maflanagan@growingedgecoaching.com?Subject=contact via website"><span style="color:#333333">maflanagan@growingedgecoaching.com</span></a></p>
    </div><!-- end contact-info -->
</div><!-- end landing-content -->
```

CSS

```
/* Landing Content */

#landing-content {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#landing-brief {
    width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#landing-brief ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#landing-brief ul li:last-child {
    padding-right: none;
}

#landing-brief #twitter-feed {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333333;
    margin-left: -28px;
}

#landing-brief #twitter-feed ul li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#landing-brief .forward-link {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: CSS doesn't know PHP. It would be more helpful if you posted the rendered HTML ("View Source" in your browser) instead of your PHP code.

Comment: Also, putting your question into http://jsfiddle.net/ (hit save, then post the new URL) will get you answers a lot quicker (people don't have to retrace your thought processes by reading code). It may also help you understand the problem better as your reconstruct your problem in simplified form.

Comment: So what you're trying to do looks something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/vxuUr/), and you want the "Read More" links to be at the bottom of the container?

Comment: @AymanSafadi, thanks for the tip. I've replaced the php with rendered HTML.

Comment: @thirdender essentially, yes. If I could have a little bit of (equal) space between the content and the link, though, that would be great.

Here is what I currently have in jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/mugUG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `LI` elements are aligned horizontally yeah?

What you want to do is give all of your `LI` elements an equal height tall enough enough to accommodate the content in each LI.

Then make the `LI` elements `position:relative`

Then make the `forward-link` elements `position:absolute, left:0, bottom:0`

That should do the trick.

Comment: Doing this stacked all of the elements on top of one another on the left side.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the above. The LI elements should be position:relative

Answer (score 0):

Give your all 3 div different id. 1st 2 div give float as left and third div float as right.
All 3 div put in main div with **overflow hidden**.

Comment: I didn't notice any change by doing this.. ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fiddle Screenshot]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/vxuUr/2/)

```
ul {
  position: relative;
}
li {
  position: static; /* The default if no position property is applied */
  padding-bottom: 1.6em;
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* Or, in the linked Fiddle, 1em to accommodate the padding
                on the bottom of the UL tag. */
}
```

This only works in IE7+ (IE6 doesn't support absolutely positioned elements with only one edge (`left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom`) property), and only when the elements are guaranteed to be side-by-side. When an element is absolutely positioned but no edge properties are specified, the browser attempts to put the element where it would be if it didn't have `position: absolute;`. Giving the element only one edge property (such as `bottom: 1em;` as in the example) causes the browser to move it from the "default" location to match that single edge property. So `left` and `right` can be left as automatically calculated if only `top` or `bottom` is specified. See also [W3C Wiki: CSS absolute and fixed positioning](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Specifying_the_position).

Make the `UL` tag `position: relative;`, but the `LI` tags `position: static;` (the default value for `position`, not absolute… absolute elements have no layout, and will require a fixed height on the parent element). Give the `LI` tags enough padding on the bottom to make space for the content you want at the bottom. In the example above, the content is one line of text, which is about 1.2em for most fonts. I added a bit more padding for spacing in the example, and made it about 1.6em. Then make the `A` tags `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` and they will move to the bottom of the nearest positioned ancestor, or in this case the `UL` tag.